# How to change color icons in react after onClick

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

```
export default function Post({post}) {

   const [like,setLike] = useState(post.like)
   const [islike,setIslike] = useState(false)

   const handler=()=>{
       setLike(islike? like-1:like+1 )
       setIslike(!islike)
       
   }
    return (
        <>
        <div className="postcontainer">
           <div className='postwrapper'>
               
          
            <div className="postTop">
                <div className="topleft">
                    <img className="images" src= {Users.filter((u)=> u.id === post.userId)[0].imagesProfile} alt="profile" />
                    <span className="names"> {Users.filter((u)=> u.id === post.userId)[0].userName} </span>
                    <span className="dates"> {post.date}</span>
                    
                </div>
                <div className="topzRight">
                <MoreVert />
                </div>
                
            </div>
            <div className="postcenter">
                
               <span className='text'>{post.descrip}</span>
               <img className="imagepost" src={post.imagesPost} alt="newpost" />

            </div>
            <div className="postbotton">
                <div className="postbottonLeft">
                <LocationOnIcon     className="icon" />
                <FavoriteIcon   className="icon" onClick={handler}/>
               
                <span className='counter' > {like} People liked it</span>
                </div>
                <div className="postbottonRight">
                <span>{post.comment} comments</span>
                <SmsOutlined className="iconcomment" />
                </div>
                
            </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
        </>
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should try to talk more about what you want to do in the code instead of just putting the question in the title and putting the code as the body.

Second, if you want some HTML element to have a different color based on when you clicked it or not, you could make a CSS class for each state you want, so one class could be `.isLiked` and the other can be `.isNotLiked` with each one having a different color. Then in your code, you can have a conditional on the `className` attribute for the HTML element to decide what it should be based on a conditional.

Eg: `className={isLiked ? 'isLiked' : 'isNotLiked'}`